# How to force Delphi 10.2.1 to generate 64 bit code for IOS app

Tags: xcode, delphi, 64-bit, delphi-ios

I am using Delphi 10.2.1 to write an IOS app but I cant get Delphi to generate 64 bit code. When I run the app in the IOS simulator I get a message telling me the code needs to be updated. Is there a compiler directive I can use to force 64 bit code generation?. I am coding on a 64 bit windows system using a x64 based processor. On the Mac: Xcode is Ver 8.3.3.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation contain the answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it does, but it is kind of buried and you have to dig it out. Another problem is that lack of 64-bit simulator compiler at this point in time is quite unexpected. You have to know there is no 64-bit compiler to know what to look for in documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Currently Delphi only supports 32-bit compiler for the iOS simulator. There is nothing you can do here. You can only generate 64-bit code for the real devices.

Delphi iOS Compilers - 10.2 Tokyo:

- DCCIOSARM, the Delphi Compiler for the 32-bit iOS Device
- DCCIOSARM64, the Delphi Compiler for the 64-bit iOS Device
- DCCIOS32, the Delphi Compiler for the iOS Simulator

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can now continue with my project without the worry that it would not work in future Is versions

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 10.3 will support 64bit compilers on MACOS this means that only with the next release of delphi it will be possibile to compile also (probably) on 64bit iOSSimulator that is based on the Mac Compiler for Intel 64.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can now continue with my project without the worry that it would not work in future Is versions